# YUI Uploader 2.6.0 example

Tags: yui, yui-uploader

I'm trying to simply use some of the examples and instructions regarding the YUI-Uploader, and I'm being frustrated by a number of issues.

1. The "YUI Library: Uploader" cheat sheet's simple use case doesn't work for me because all the listed methods except `addListener()` do not exist on the myUploader object.
2. The [example](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/uploader/uploader-simple.html) is for version 2.5.1 and includes a method called `browse()`, which not only was removed in version 2.6.0 but I cannot find any documentation for how to use the 2.5.1 version if I so choose.
3. I can't find the source FLA to the `uploader.swf` file so that I could theoretically diagnose all these issues.

Has anyone successfully used the 2.6.0 YUI Uploader, and if so is there some common interfering JavaScript I should avoid, or a better example to follow?  Thank you.

Thanks for the replies.

I might note that I finished my "uploader" project before receiving any responses to this.
Part of my problems were due to some of the examples being for v2.5.1 and another part were due to not using an event listener to see when the component was ready.  I got the most help from just dissecting what [Flickr](http://flickr.com) did.

Comment: I feel weird getting a popular question badge on this. It doesn't fit my definition of popular. It took months to get answers, it has only 2, which are almost as dated as the question, it may have 1000 views but only a couple votes on the answer or question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the source to `uploader.swf` [here at `Uploader.as`](http://github.com/yui/yui2/blob/fa7794624ce8dd3d3b231289ca1995c25bebecc4/src/uploader/as/Uploader.as) now that the YUI source is available on GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

You've got the wrong link for the simple example, here's the correct one.

[YUI Uploader Simple Example](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/uploader/uploader-simple-button.html)

You could also take a look at my implementation if you'd like, it's pretty barebones and works fine using YUI 2.6.0.

[Tivac.com YUI Uploader Implementation](http://tivac.com/upload/)

It sounds like for #1 that you're trying to call methods on the uploader immediately. You should instead add listeners for all the events it can fire and do any configuration once the "contentReady" event fires. All the YUI examples & mine do that, so you can check there for a code sample.